# c# SortedSet how to get an element out

Tags: c#, .net, sortedset

I am pretty new to this so forgive my noobishness here.

I am trying to edit an item in a c# sortedset if I find that the item exists.  So I can use list.contains(value) and find that the value does exist in the list.  But how do I get that item out of the list.  Here is what I have.  This gets really slow as my list size gets really big, so I'm guessing there must be a better way than this.

```
if (list.Contains(p))
{
     Person exists = list.First(person => person.Name.Equals(line[0]));
     // do something here to exists
}
else
{
    // just add the person to the list
}
```

Comment: This is why the C++ std collections is the only well designed collections I know of. I have no idea why C# and Java didn't return iterators from their find methods pointing to the found element. Maybe I just wanted to find an element in order to grab the next largest element (which, yes, I have needed in code, and is easy in C++ sorted collections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need `SortedSet` which is red-black tree? If you don't need sorting, you shouldn't use it. Have you considered `HashSet` or `Dictionary` instead which is more suitable (fast) for getting item by key?

In your case you probably need to create `Dictionary` instance with key equals to person name, i.e.:

```
Dictionary<string, Person> list;
```

Then you can get person by it's name, complexity is O(1)

```
if(list.ContainsKey(line[0]))
{
    list[line[0]]...
}
```

or even better:

```
Person p;

if(list.TryGetValue(line[0], out p))
{
    p...
)
```

Comment: Well I guess I don't have to have them sorted.  Sorted would be nice but I can deal with them not being sorted. How can I get an item from a hashset by key?

Comment: I just realized that I could use this code instead and its much much faster.  Person exists = list.FirstOrDefault(person => person.Name == p.Name);  I don't know why I was using Where.  That was slowing everything down to a crawl because as my list grew it was having to search through more and more names....Ugh.

Comment: @MatthewTheTerrible, :) Anyway, you can check out `Dictionary`

Comment: Oh, yes I like your way much better.

Comment: This does not answer OP's original question

Comment: which data-structure c# dictionary is based on?

Comment: @SuB, hashtable

Answer (score 3):

As of .NET Framework 4.7.2 there is [TryGetValue method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) available for SortedSet.

Comment: Note that the `SortedSet.TryGetValue()` method *does not remove* any item, it just gives a matching element, if any.

Answer (score 2):

*For the .NET Frameworks older than the version 4.7.2:*

It is **not possible** to get an element from `SortedSet` or `HashSet` collections (using the `Contains` method or somehow else). One can just get to know whether the collection contains the element. Since in order to find this element in the collection, one already uses this element (passing it to the `Contains` method), it can be assumed that one **already has** this element.

*For the .NET Frameworks starting from the version 4.7.2:*

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50446121/2199512) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using the [PowerCollections](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/PowerCollections) project — it has a lot of useful improvements to the standard generic collections.